# Polling API possible in Salesforce

Tags: apex

I am integrating a third party in an apex class and wants to call that class after every 0.5 seconds for 3 seconds till i get my preferred response from them. Is it possible in salesforce?

Comment: Maybe [Streamin API](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/api_basics/units/api_basics_streaming) is suitable for your requirenemnt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a [continuation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Continuation.htm) callout. The system will automatically continue when an appropriate response has been received. Examples are in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use actionPoller in VF to your advantage,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm

If you are using Lightining then probably using setInterval in Javascript https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682622/using-setinterval-to-do-simplistic-continuous-polling

If you can look for a more advanced solution using Streaming API suits this job,(Currently Streaming API client support is only available for Classic) . Lightning support for Streaming API client is to be available in W19(Safe harbour)

Comment: Yes, but actionPoller is limited to 5000 ms minimum

Comment: the streaming API is for tracking changes to data in salesforce - I think this use case is to check non-salesforce systems for updates.